# How to create a dict from the list using nextflow to map groupkey

Tags: nextflow

I have a list in nextflow
`chr_frequency.toList().view()`

```
[[chr1, 70], [chr2, 50], [chr3, 45]]
```

and wnat to convert into a map like:

```
[ "chr1": 70, "chr2": 50, "chr2": 45 ]
```

I need this format to map with `groupKey`

```
test.out.map { chr, bcf -> tuple( groupKey(chr, chr_frequency[chr]), bcf.flatten() ) }.groupTuple( by: 0 ).view()
```

I have tried:

```
chr_frequency
    .flatten()
    .view()
chr21
3
chr22
3
    .toSpreadMap()
```

`"Missing process or function toSpreadMap()"`

try2

```
chr_frequency
    .collate(2).collectEntries().view()
```

`Missing process or function collectEntries()`

using ubuntu 22.04 - openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16

Comment: `list.collectEntries()`?

Comment: what @tim_yates said, with next best `list.flatten().toSpreadMap()`

Comment: @PaulKing @tim_yates thanks. Getting error...
`chunk_frequency`
    `.flatten().view()`
chr21
3
chr22
3
    `.toSpreadMap()`

"Missing process or function toSpreadMap()"

Comment: What are you using here? Half of the functions are not from "Groovy". What is `tuple`, `groupKey`, `view`...?

Comment: @cfrick I'm using these function in the nextflow workflow

Comment: If you have a vanilla Groovy, `toSpreadMap()` should exist for `List`s since Groovy 1.8 and for `Iterable`s since Groovy 2.4. The `collectEntries` should exist for `Iterable`s and `Iterator`s since Groovy 1.8.7. You need to find out the type of your list or convert what you have to a list first.